# two models on one page MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, models

I am trying to bind two models on one page..

using this mehotd: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1108855/ways-to-Bind-Multiple-Models-on-a-View-in-MVC

I made a controller and it seems to work fine, except for one thind, The "list".  It cannot implicitly convert type List to Model:

```
public class MissiesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Missies
        public ActionResult GetMissieTombola()
        {
            MissieTombolaTagsViewModel MTTVM = new MissieTombolaTagsViewModel();
            MTTVM.Tombola = GetTombolaModel();
            MTTVM.Tags = GetTagsModel();

            return View(MTTVM);
        }

        public MissiesTombola GetTombolaModel()
        {
            MissiesTombola bModel = new MissiesTombola()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Omschrijving = "Tombola-item: Tas Douwe Egberts met zakje 75 gr. Dessertkoffie geschonken door Colruyt en een Indonesisch doekje met 1 BodyLotion en 1 DoucheGel",
                Foto = "http://www.jeroenchristens.com/Koffie.png"
            };

            return bModel;
        }

        public List GetTagsModel()
        {
            List tModel = new List();
            tModel.Add(new MissieTombolaTag() { Id = 1, TagId = 1, CatId = 1, OmschrijvingCat = "Koffie", icon = "http://www.jeroenchristens.com/Koffie.png" });
            tModel.Add(new MissieTombolaTag() { Id = 1, TagId = 2, CatId = 2, OmschrijvingCat = "Keuken", icon = "http://www.jeroenchristens.com/Keukenitems.png" });
            tModel.Add(new MissieTombolaTag() { Id = 1, TagId = 3, CatId = 3, OmschrijvingCat = "Badkamer", icon = "http://www.jeroenchristens.com/Badkameritems.png" });
            return tModel;


        }
    }

    public class List
    {
        internal void Add(MissieTombolaTag missieTombolaTag)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgxtI.png)

Comment: Please show how MissieTombolaTagsViewModel is declared.

Answer (score 0):

The property `Tags` of the class `MissieTombolaTagsViewModel` is declared to be of type `MissieTombolaTag`, but you try to assign a `List` to it. Declare the property `Tag` to be of type `List`.